# Function to output multiple files with variable names

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a folder full of files of various similar names. I am trying to use PowerShell to take each file and create a text file with the same name in a different location.

I tried to run the following code, the output of `$list` shows all the files I intend to copy the names of.

```
$list = Get-Child-Item E:\Folder -include ('.TIB') #store files to be copied


foreach ($file in $list) 
{
    Out-File -PSPath 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\$file.txt'
}
```

When I run this, I end up with a single file in the destination folder called `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes when you want to reference the contents of a variable. You also likely only want the `BaseName` (i.e. filename without the extension), so you have to escape that.

Code:

```
$list = Get-Child-Item E:\Folder -include ('.TIB') #store files to be copied

foreach ($file in $list) {
    Out-File -PSPath "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\$($file.BaseName).txt"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Can you explain the mechanics of the $($varname) syntax? I appreciate your time.